# Dax Measure : COUNT Unique Articles Week over Week

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a huge transactional table that shows me the weekly sales.
The columns are

- Year-Week
- Product
- Value

Now I would like to determine, how many new products were sold this week compared to last week.
DISTINCTCOUNT will not work here, right? Do I need CALCULATEDTABLE?
How would you do that?

Comment: DISTINCTCOUNT will work, you have to apply appropriate filter using CALCULATE to get what you want. Depending on type of your year-week column, use DATESBETWEEN or FILTER function.

Comment: Also, if this week vs last week is used for many measures, consider using calculation groups. You will need TabularEditor to create calculation groups in power bi

Comment: If you provide some sample data, I can give you a working sample.